# Removing elements from mutable lists

Tags: scala

I want to choose an element and then remove it from a mutable list in O(1) time.
In C++ I could do

```
std::list<Foo> lst;
std::list<Foo>::iterator it = //some choice
//And then, possibly in another function,
lst.erase(it);
```

Can I have equivalent code in Scala, or do I have to do filter or diff?

Edit: to clarify, I want to separate choice and removal. I want to mark an element so that it can be later quickly accessed, modified and possibly removed. It would be great if I could insert another element after the selected one too. That's the functionality C++ iterators give.

Comment: The C++ approach is not O(1), it's O(n).  The act of removing the item is constant, but finding it is O(n).

Comment: @DerekWyatt Right. I was only referring to removing.

Comment: Why not explore the scaladoc of some `mutable list` yourself?

Comment: @xiefei, of course I did. I found that Scala Iterator does not do this. ArrayBuffer has remove(index) but that is not O(1) and, more importantly, removing one element may make other indices invalid. LinkedList doesn't seem to have any remove at all and while I could probably make it work with next, I don't think it's a good idea. I can't use Set as I may have duplicates. Unless there is a MultiSet I didn't notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do O(1) removal, I think your only option is to search the respective inner linked lists (with `next`) and keep a reference.

If you use a `mutable.DoubleLinkedList` things will become a bit easier:

```
val li = DoubleLinkedList(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val elem = li.next.next.next // O(< n) until you find what you want
elem.remove() // O(1)

li == DoubleLinkedList(1,2,3,5,6)
```

But even then, you won’t have a complete mirror of C++s mutable iterator interface.

I am not sure there is a proper Scala list which would support something like that. An alternative suggestion would be to use a [Zipper](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/Zipper.scala.html) which also provides O(1) for operations at the position of the zipper.

Answer (score 3):

Look at `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer` for example (there are others, of course, but you didn't say what collection you were interested in, so I just picked one):

```
val a = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)
a -= 3
```

That's the same semantics as your C++ version (but it's still O(n), just like the C++ version).

Comment: `a -= 3` doesn't seem to be an uniform approach. Consider `ArrayBuffer(3, 1, 2, 3, 4)`, can't delete second `3` with `-=`

Comment: I don't know what "uniform" means in this context.  If you want to delete both threes, then use `filter`.  If you want to delete the second three (assuming you know there is a second one) then you have to find it first... The solution above fits the C++ version, which is what the question was about.

Comment: I'm okay with any collection that can contain duplicates. Though one that preserves order would be preferred.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i remove an element from a MutableList