# Removing an element from MutableList in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, mutable

I have a `MutableList` and I want to remove an element from it but I cannot find the appropriate method.  There is a method to remove element from `ListBuffer` like this:

```
val x = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
x -= 5
```

I am unable to find an equivalent method on `MutableList`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing elements from mutable lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575050/removing-elements-from-mutable-lists)

Comment: the question you refferd was has the answers for ArrayBuffer
i have searched and found the same solution for ListBuffer but that solution doesnot work with MutableList that i am using

Comment: The accepted answer is clearly a mutable.DoubleLinkedList

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you to use them - they're pretty tricky: https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/3cc99d7b4aa43b1b06cc837a55665896993235fc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MutableList` lacks `-=` and `--=` because it does not extend the [`Shrinkable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.generic.Shrinkable) trait.  Various motivations for this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5446744/1223622).

`MutableList` does have `diff`, `filter`, and other methods which can help you in case you are in a situation where reassigning a variable (or instantiating a new variable) might be an option, and performance concerns aren't paramount:

```
var mylist = MutableList(1, 2, 3)
mylist = mylist diff Seq(1)
val myNewList = mylist.filter(_ != 2)
val indexFiltered = mylist.zipWithIndex.collect { case (el, ind) if ind != 1 => el }
```

You can often use [`ListBuffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer) instead of `MutableList`, which will unlock the desired `-=` and `--=` methods:

```
val mylist = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3)
mylist -= 1 //mylist is now ListBuffer(2, 3)
mylist --= Seq(2, 3) //mylist is now empty
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the answer, just to warn you about problems (at least in 2.11.x):

```
//street magic
scala> val a = mutable.MutableList(1,2,3)
a: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Int] = MutableList(1, 2, 3)
scala> a += 4
res7: a.type = MutableList(1, 2, 3, 4)
scala> a
res8: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Int] = MutableList(1, 2, 3, 4)
scala> a ++= List(8,9,10)
res9: a.type = MutableList(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10)
scala> val b = a.tail
b: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Int] = MutableList(2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10)
scala> b.length
res10: Int = 6
scala> a.length
res11: Int = 7
scala> a ++= List(8,9,10)
res12: a.type = MutableList(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 8, 9, 10)
scala> b += 7
res13: b.type = MutableList(2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 7)
scala> a
res14: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Int] = MutableList(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 7) 
scala> b
res15: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Int] = MutableList(2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 7)
scala> a ++= List(8,9,10)
res16: a.type = MutableList(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 7)
```

This example is taken from some gist - I've posted it on facebook with #devid_blein #street_magic tags, but can't find original link on the internet.